# same file in static lib and project

Tags: c++, version-control

- I have a static singleton, logger-class (if you like it or not), that I use in all of my projects.
- I have made static library that is also using that singleton, logger-class, let's say a half year ago. I made quit some changes to the mentioned logger-class in the meantime, but I didn't update the static lib.
- Now I started a new project that uses the lib and the latest(!) logger-class. However I don't want to update the lib, because then I would have to go through all my project and check if they are still working.

So my question is: Can it cause a conflict, if I have two different versions of a class in my static lib and my actual project, especially if its static stuff? And if so, can that conflict be eliminated by using a namespace for the static lib-stuff? I hope this is clear enough to understand...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Please let me know if anything is unclear, which seems to be the case since I don't get any answers.

Comment: Am I not patient enough? Is this question too simple or too tough? Why don't I get any answers. :-/

Comment: Have you even tried linking your "new" application that uses the "new" logger header files with the "old" static library file? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem fully, but you can consider naming the new version of your library differently (using a version number for example). This way, you don't change anything to your existing projects, but you link the new ones with the latest version of your lib.